# Output cfquery results in array of structures?

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, structure

I have query with multiple columns that should be organized like this:

```
Array One = [
     Line1 = [{value:"15",m:1,nr:0},{value:"25",m:1,nr:1},{value:"0",m:0,nr:0},
     {value:"75",m:0,nr:0}],
     Line2 = [{value:"35",m:0,nr:0},{value:"5",m:1,nr:0},{value:"80",m:1,nr:0},
     {value:"95",m:0,nr:0}],
    ]
```

So above I have one array that will have sub arrays inside. Each sub array represents new line. In each sub array there is a structure with the `value`, `m` and `nr` keys. My question sis how I can do this dynamically? Here is example of my query:

```
 <cfquery name="getRec" datasource="Test">
    SELECT 
  hs_ra0,hs_ra1,hs_ra2,hs_ra3,hs_ra4,hs_ra5,hs_ra6,hs_ra7,hs_ra8,hs_ra9,hs_ra10,        
            hs_ra0m,hs_ra1m,hs_ra2m,hs_ra3m,hs_ra4m,hs_ra5m,hs_ra6m,hs_ra7m,hs_ra8m,hs_ra9m,hs_ra10m,
            hs_ra0nr,hs_ra1nr,hs_ra2nr,hs_ra3nr,hs_ra4nr,hs_ra5nr,hs_ra6nr,hs_ra7nr,hs_ra8nr,hs_ra9nr,hs_ra10nr,
            hs_la0,hs_la1,hs_la2,hs_la3,hs_la4,hs_la5,hs_la6,hs_la7,hs_la8,hs_la9,hs_la10,
            hs_la0m,hs_la1m,hs_la2m,hs_la3m,hs_la4m,hs_la5m,hs_la6m,hs_la7m,hs_la8m,hs_la9m,hs_la10m,
            hs_la0nr,hs_la1nr,hs_la2nr,hs_la3nr,hs_la4nr,hs_la5nr,hs_la6nr,hs_la7nr,hs_la8nr,hs_la9nr,hs_la10nr
    FROM Records WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE recID = '118976'
 </cfquery>
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
<cfset grData = structNew()>
<cfset grArray = arrayNew(1)>
<cfset raArray = arrayNew(1)>

<cfset count = 0>
<cfoutput query="getRec">
    <cfset structInsert(grData,"val"&count,hs_ra0)>
    <cfset structInsert(grData,"mask"&count,hs_ra0m)>
    <cfset structInsert(grData,"nr"&count,hs_ra0nr)>
    <cfset arrayAppend(raArray, grData)>
    <cfset count++>
    <cfset structInsert(grData,"val"&count,hs_ra1)>
    <cfset structInsert(grData,"mask"&count,hs_ra1m)>
    <cfset structInsert(grData,"nr"&count,hs_ra1nr)>
    <cfset arrayAppend(raArray, grData)>
    <cfset count++>
</cfoutput>
<cfset arrayAppend(grArray, raArray)>
```

Code above produced next output:

```
array
1   
array
1   
struct
mask0   1
mask1   0
nr0     0
nr1     1
val0    75
val1    0
2   
struct
mask0   1
mask1   0
nr0     0
nr1     1
val0    75
val1    0
```

Here is second solution that I found so far:

```
<cfoutput query="getRec">
    <cfset raArray = [{"value"=hs_ra0,"mask"=hs_ra0m,"nr"=hs_ra0nr},{"value"=hs_ra1,"mask"=hs_ra1m,"nr"=hs_ra1nr},{"value"=hs_ra2,"mask"=hs_ra2m,"nr"=hs_ra2nr},{"value"=hs_ra3,"mask"=hs_ra3m,"nr"=hs_ra3nr},
                        {"value"=hs_ra4,"mask"=hs_ra4m,"nr"=hs_ra4nr},{"value"=hs_ra5,"mask"=hs_ra5m,"nr"=hs_ra5nr},{"value"=hs_ra6,"mask"=hs_ra6m,"nr"=hs_ra6nr},{"value"=hs_ra7,"mask"=hs_ra7m,"nr"=hs_ra7nr},
                        {"value"=hs_ra8,"mask"=hs_ra8m,"nr"=hs_ra8nr},{"value"=hs_ra9,"mask"=hs_ra9m,"nr"=hs_ra9nr},{"value"=hs_ra10,"mask"=hs_ra10m,"nr"=hs_ra10nr}]>
    <cfset laArray = [{"value"=hs_la0,"mask"=hs_la0m,"nr"=hs_la0nr},{"value"=hs_la1,"mask"=hs_la1m,"nr"=hs_la1nr},{"value"=hs_la2,"mask"=hs_la2m,"nr"=hs_la2nr},{"value"=hs_la3,"mask"=hs_la3m,"nr"=hs_la3nr},
    {"value"=hs_la4,"mask"=hs_la4m,"nr"=hs_la4nr},{"value"=hs_la5,"mask"=hs_la5m,"nr"=hs_la5nr},{"value"=hs_la6,"mask"=hs_la6m,"nr"=hs_la6nr},{"value"=hs_la7,"mask"=hs_la7m,"nr"=hs_la7nr},
    {"value"=hs_la8,"mask"=hs_la8m,"nr"=hs_la8nr},{"value"=hs_ra9,"mask"=hs_ra9m,"nr"=hs_ra9nr},{"value"=hs_ra10,"mask"=hs_ra10m,"nr"=hs_ra10nr}]>

<cfset rbArray = [{"value"=hs_rb0,"mask"=hs_rb0m,"nr"=hs_rb0nr},{"value"=hs_rb1,"mask"=hs_rb1m,"nr"=hs_rb1nr},{"value"=hs_rb2,"mask"=hs_rb2m,"nr"=hs_rb2nr},{"value"=hs_rb3,"mask"=hs_rb3m,"nr"=hs_rb3nr},
{"value"=hs_rb4,"mask"=hs_rb4m,"nr"=hs_rb4nr},{"value"=hs_rb5,"mask"=hs_rb5m,"nr"=hs_rb5nr},{"value"=hs_rb6,"mask"=hs_rb6m,"nr"=hs_rb6nr},{"value"=hs_rb7,"mask"=hs_rb7m,"nr"=hs_rb7nr},
{"value"=hs_rb8,"mask"=hs_rb8m,"nr"=hs_rb8nr},{"value"=hs_rb9,"mask"=hs_rb9m,"nr"=hs_rb9nr},{"value"=hs_rb10,"mask"=hs_rb10m,"nr"=hs_rb10nr}]>
```

```
<cfset sfArray = [{"value"=hs_sf0},{"value"=hs_sf1},{"value"=hs_sf2},{"value"=hs_sf3},{"value"=hs_sf4},{"value"=hs_sf5},{"value"=hs_sf6},{"value"=hs_sf7},{"value"=hs_sf8},{"value"=hs_sf9},{"value"=hs_sf10}]>
<cfset sfaArray = [{"value"=hs_sfa0},{"value"=hs_sfa1},{"value"=hs_sfa2},{"value"=hs_sfa3},{"value"=hs_sfa4},{"value"=hs_sfa5},{"value"=hs_sfa6},{"value"=hs_sfa7},{"value"=hs_sfa8},{"value"=hs_sfa9},{"value"=hs_sfa10}]>
```

I got desired output but I'm wondering if this hard coded solution can be simplified or produced dynamically?

Seems that same values are showing in each sub array.

If anyone can help with how to organize this please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Seems much more complicated than necessary.  Will your query always return 1 row at the most?

Comment: @DanBracuk when you say 1 row do you mean one record at the time or?

Comment: Your query is filtering on a recId = something.  How many records does it return.

Comment: @DanBracuk Only one record at the time.

Comment: You need to put the `<cfset grData = structNew()>` inside the `<cfoutput>` (which should be a `<cfloop>`) and declare a second  `<cfset grData = structNew()>` for the next array.  I don't know why, but CF holds onto to struct data when looping unless the struct is reinitialized...at least, that's been my experience.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function qResultToArrayOfStruct(qResult){
        var array = [];

        if(qResult.RecordCount > 0){
            var key_list = qResult.getColumnList();
            
            cfloop(query=qResult){
                var struct = {};

                for (key in key_list) {
                    struct["#Key#"] = qResult["#Key#"][qResult.currentRow];
                }
                
                array.append(struct);
            }
        }

        return array;
    }
```